# Move N items in k days ((N>=k)

Tags: algorithm

You want to move N items in k days (N>=k). You have to move at least one item per day. The items are listed in an array P, where P[i] is the size of item i.
You can move items i only if all the items from 0 to
[i-1] are already moved. Everyday you need a container to pack the item and move it. The container size need for the day i is the maximum
item size moved on that day.
Given k days and array P as the item sizes, find out the minimum total container size required to move all the items.

Examples

**input**

arr={10,2,20,5,15,10,1}

days=3

**output**
day1=[10,2,20,5,15]. Container size =20

day2=[10]. Container size=10

day3=[1]. Container size=1

minimum total size 31

**input**

arr={10,2,20,5,15,10,1}

days=5

day1=[10]

day2=[2]

day3=[20,5,15]

day4=[10]

day5=[1]

minimum total size 43

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int minimumContainer(int items[], int days) {
        int k = 1;
        int left = 0;
        int right = items.length - 1;
        int minimumContainer = 0;
        while (left <= right && k < days) {
            if (items[left] < items[right] || (items[left]==items[right] && isLeft(items, left, right))) {
                minimumContainer = minimumContainer + items[left];
                left++;
            } else {
                minimumContainer = minimumContainer + items[right];
                right--;
            }
            k++;
        }
        int max = 0;
        while (left <= right) {
            if (items[left] > max) {
                max = items[left];
            }
            left++;
        }
        minimumContainer = minimumContainer + max;
        return minimumContainer;
    }


private static boolean isLeft(int items[],int left, int right) {
    while(left<right) {
        if(items[left]<items[right]) {
            return true;
        }
        left++;
        right--;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. In this case, at the very least, you should indicate what language the code is.

Answer (score -1):

This seems some modification of the `job scheduling` problem

It can be solved using the DP approach effectively.

Here is the python code using the DP approch.

```
 def minContainerSize(self, A, d):
    n = len(A)
    if n < d: return -1
    dp, dp2 = [float('inf')] * n, [0] * n
    for d in range(d):
        stack = []
        for i in range(d, n):
            dp2[i] = dp[i - 1] + A[i] if i else A[i]
            while stack and A[stack[-1]] <= A[i]:
                j = stack.pop()
                dp2[i] = min(dp2[i], dp2[j] - A[j] + A[i])
            if stack:
                dp2[i] = min(dp2[i], dp2[stack[-1]])
            stack.append(i)
        dp, dp2 = dp2, dp
    return dp[-1]
```

Used stack in above approach to reduce some time complexity

Time complexity `O(nd)`

Space complexity  `O(n)`